# Any standard tests to prevent hacking?

Tags: xss, javascript, java, automated-testing

I am very new in programming world so my question may sound weird. I am useing selenium to test an application, yesterday one of my colleagues found this issue that if someone enters this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> alert("This is an example of what will happen"); </script>
```

in a text-box where they are supposed to enter their names it will cause some problems, it's kinda like hacking!!! how can I figure out the same issues? should I be a hacker or there are some standard tests for websites(or applications) to check this kind of problems, especially for log in part?

Comment: There are website scanners that perform very basic hacking tests. They are a place to start but a very simplistic and incomplete solution.

Comment: @schroeder could you give some links of those websites please? I really appreciate it.

Comment: There are many, many options: here is a review site of features and effectiveness: http://www.sectoolmarket.com/price-and-feature-comparison-of-web-application-scanners-unified-list.html

Comment: I would recommend looking at the [OWASP top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10) and getting familiar with what they are and how to prevent them. It's basically a list of the 10 biggest attack vectors used in previous years. The link is by no means complete but a great place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* use a scanner to guide you, but you need start with secure coding.  Use a scanner to test for verification after you have implemented the secure coding concepts.  First rule of secure coding is [See input as evil](https://adtmag.com/articles/2003/04/15/rule-of-secure-coding-see-input-as-evil.aspx).

The first step to not trusting input in a web application is to encode (not filter) all user input.  So, your input example will be HTML encoded to

```
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt; 
alert(&quot;This is an example of what will happen&quot;); &lt;/script&gt;
```

Which will be interpreted by your browser as text and not as code.

Also see [the OWASP Secure coding cheat sheet.](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Secure_Coding_Cheat_Sheet)